# How to tell Android NDK to use a different toolchain

Tags: android, android-ndk, toolchain

I've downloaded a custom toolchain ([linaro](http://www.linaro.org/downloads/)) to build ARM based Android apps. How do I tell the NDK to use it? Can I define or set something in Android.mk and Application.mk that would allow me to do that? Is there another way?

Comment: Did you do this on Ubuntu?  How did you install the toolchain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the other answer mentions, toolchains are discovered by ndk-build makefile system in `$(NDK_ROOT)/toolchains/` and you can mirror ideas you see there. But there are a few extra concepts for supporting non-Android target platforms that are interesting although they may be soon outdated as ndk-build starts to explicitly support other platforms, such as mingw targeting win32 (or other gcc compilers targeting plain 'ol linux).

In `config.mk`:

```
TOOLCHAIN_ABIS := (list of ABIs that the toolchain supports)
```

This is an important definition, because you can use this name in your Application.mk to build using the toolchain for a particular ABI. One of the benefits of corrupting the usage of this definition, is that ndk-build can simultaneously build for multiple ABIs.  It *always* assumes that the platform is Android, but if you want to target win32 using a mingw based toolchain, you can define an "ABI" as `x86-win32`, and then use this ABI in your `Application.mk` to select it as an additional target via `APP_ABI:= x86-win32`  Then in your `Android.mk` files you can use the `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` definition to select win32 specific sources and include paths, for example:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86-win32)
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES += my_win32_file.c
  LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSOME_WIN32_SPECIFIC
endif
```

The final piece is that in `setup.mk` for your toolchain, it may be insufficient to look at other toolchains as examples, because what `setup.mk` for a particular toolchain *really* does is override build settings in `default-build-commands.mk`, so what you want to do is inspect that file, and redefine things in it that you don't like.

Following the previous example, mingw does not support the noexec flag in the binaries, and you can get rid of this feature by adding the following lines in your `setup.mk`:

```
# These flags are used to enforce the NX (no execute) security feature in the
# generated machine code. This adds a special section to the generated shared
# libraries that instruct the Linux kernel to disable code execution from
# the stack and the heap.
TARGET_NO_EXECUTE_CFLAGS  := # our platform doesn't support this flag!
TARGET_NO_EXECUTE_LDFLAGS := # our platform doesn't support this flag!

# These flags disable the above security feature
TARGET_DISABLE_NO_EXECUTE_CFLAGS  :=  # our platform doesn't support this flag!
TARGET_DISABLE_NO_EXECUTE_LDFLAGS :=  # our platform doesn't support this flag!
```

This is just one example of the many features in `default-build-commands.mk` that may need to be overridden, and of course it's important to provide `TOOLCHAIN_NAME` so that the toolchain can be selected via `NDK_TOOLCHAIN` variable inside your `Application.mk` file in addition to the ABI methodology I mention above.

Answer (score 10):

The NDK makefile system is quite extensible and you can indeed define a different toolchain. You'll need some understanding of how Make works.

Toolchains are discovered and initialized in `build/core/init.mk` line 261 (in NDKr6, the line # may change in future versions). The initialization code looks for files named `config.mk` under `$(NDK_ROOT)/toolchains/*`. So you'll need to add your toolchain in a subdirectory under the NDK toolchains directory, and add a `config.mk` and `setup.mk` to that subdirectory. Look at `toolchains/x86-4.4.3` and `toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3` for examples. You should be able to cut and paste the ARM toolchain `config.mk` and `setup.mk` if your toolchain has a standard layout.

Once you've defined a toolchain in the toolchain directory, you can switch to it by setting the `NDK_TOOLCHAIN` variable inside your `Application.mk` file.

Answer (score 0):

well，you can simply add  "NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION = 4.9" in your Application.mk